# How to get image name from resourceid in android?

Tags: android

```
int igotit = getResources().getIdentifier(val, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

i got resourceid from that how to display imagename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this :

```
String imageName = getResources().getResourceName(R.id.img);
```

refer [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) . there is also the method : [getResourceEntryName(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

To use the method

```
getResources().getIdentifier(val, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

the `val` **is** the image name

check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)